# Set at the same level the unit of two yaxis highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to set at the same level 2 yAxis with highcharts. Because it's difficult to explain what I want, this picture should help you to understand :

[image]

I want to align the two "0" value of my 2 charts.

This is my current code :

```
$(function () {
        $('#tresorerieChart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // First yAxis
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}°C',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            { // Third yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value} mm',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Rainfall',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [49.9, -71.5, 106.4, -129.2, 144.0, -176.0, -135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, -95.6, 54.4],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mm'
                }

            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [-7.0, -6.9, -9.5, -14.5, -18.2, -21.5, -25.2, -26.5, -23.3, -18.3, -13.9, -9.6],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Temperature',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a feature request for this functionality here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2554384-multiple-axis-alignment-control feel free to vote and comment.

Comment: I just tested it and it didn't work :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... it's a feature request. You can vote for it to move it up the priority list for Highcharts to implement such a feature natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long time ago I have created example how to align two yAxis to the same value, you can find this here: http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/414/

Code responsible for linking axes:

```
var i = 15;
while (chart.yAxis[1].translate(0) != chart.yAxis[0].translate(0) && i > 0) {
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().min - chart.yAxis[0].translate(chart.yAxis[1].translate(0), true));
    i--;
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what this snippet is doing? I don't understand the role of translate here.

Comment: `translate` is an old version for `toPixels` and `toValue` (before those were added to API). Here is example with `toPixels` and `toValue`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3wt5mu4c/

Comment: Is `i` a random number here?

Comment: Yes, it's a max number of iterations to find matching extremes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It looks like it doesn't always work in our app. We sometimes have a big dataset and we use the drilldown functionality as well. Increasing the iterations would just slow things down.